# I must calculate the yield "taux_act" from two columns of my dataframe as below :

Tags: python

```
df['maturite'] = df["Date d'échéance"] - df['Date de la valeur']## df['maturite'] > .. ..days 

def taux_act(t,m):
    if m < timedelta(days =365):
        taux = ((1 + t * m)/360)**(365/m)-1
    else:
        taux = t

df['taux'] = taux_act(df['Taux moyen pondéré'],df['maturite'])
```

I got this error :

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the function

Comment: df['taux'] = taux_act(df['Taux moyen pondéré'],df['maturite']

Comment: I have two columns : Taux moyen pondéré and maturite.The column "maturite" is the difference between two dates in my DataFrame.I want to add a column in my DataFrame that caculate the yield "taux_act"function that i defined.

Comment: @Sangeerththan Balachandran df['taux'] = taux_act(df['Taux moyen pondéré'],df['maturite'])

Comment: Here the issue is your m variable is not returning as datatype time delta64[ns]

Comment: @Sangeerththan Balachandran Can you edit my code please ?

Comment: def taux_act(t,m):
    if m < 365:
        taux = ((1 + t * m)/360)**(365/m)-1
    else:
        taux = t  . I got the same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data type of m in your function to timedelta64[ns] as below.

```
df['maturite'] = df["Date d'échéance"].astype('timedelta64[D]')- df['Date de la valeur'].astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: @ Sangeerththan Balachandran it doesn't work def taux_act(t,m):
    df['maturite'] = df["Date d'échéance"].values.astype('timedelta64[ns]') - df['Date de la valeur'].values.astype(
        'timedelta64[ns]')
    if m < timedelta(days=365):
        taux = ((1 + t * m)/360)**(365/m)-1
    else:
        taux = t

Comment: @ Sangeerththan Balachandran `def date_convert(date_to_convert):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to_convert,'%d/%m/%Y')'

'df['Date de la valeur'] = df['Date de la valeur'].apply(date_convert)'
'df["Date d'échéance"] = df["Date d'échéance"].apply(date_convert)'

'df['maturite'] = df["Date d'échéance"] - df['Date de la valeur']'
'print(df)'
'def taux_act(t,m):
    if m < 365:
        taux = ((1 + t * m)/360)**(365/m)-1
    else:
        taux = t
df['taux'] = taux_act(df['Taux moyen pondéré'],df['maturite'])`This is my code at the moment.i still get error

Comment: Still you got the error as same type or now you have changed the date format.

Comment: @ Sangeerththan Balachandran Can i send you the code file ?

Comment: You have to find the type properly and have to convert to the same type in your if clause.

Comment: @ Sangeerththan Balachandran Can you explain more ?

Comment: 'Date d'échéance        datetime64[ns]
Transaction                    object
Taux moyen pondéré             object
Date de la valeur      datetime64[ns]
maturite              timedelta64[ns]'
dtype: object